# jquery not running from <body>

Tags: jquery

I'm calling a function that's loaded in custom js file in the header.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/my.js"></script>
```

my.js has

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function testFunction(){ 
        alert("inside testfunction");
    }
});
```

after a few clicks, this is loaded in the `<body>`:

```
$("#someid").live($.myapp.event.play, function(event) {
    alert("this works");
    testFunction();
});
```

the alert "this works", fires, but then nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When debugging javascript make sure you have something up that will show you any JS errors.  Firebug is a good one (good just for all-around web development).  I'm pretty sure you would have gotten a testFunction is not a function kind of error which may have helped you narrow the problem down.

Comment: yeah, I did, wasn't sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scoping issue. When you define variables (or objects, such as a function) in the `$(document).ready` function they are temporary.

```
var x = 1;
var y;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x= 'a billiondy'; //does not affect the global variable
    y=2;
    z=3;
    window.a = 4;
});
```

At this point `window` has 3 variables, `x`, `y`,and `a` which are equal to 1,2, and 4 respectively.

Because `x` is redeclared with `var`, it is not overwritten (it is a local variable only).

Because `y` was defined in `window`, the scope chain finds y and assumes you meant `window.y`.

Because `z` was `null` (never declared) the ready function now declares a local variable. When the ready function closes, `z` is not referred to in any active scope, so it is garbage collected.

The same thing happens to `a`, but it is not garbage collected because you explicitly said "this is a window variable". Thus `a` is defined in the global scope. Got it?

EDIT: That is more of an answer than you wanted, but understanding this is important. At some point you'll ask "why was such and such variable overwritten/undefined". The answer is in the scope chain.

Second edit:

To answer Andre's question (see comments), the following code is invalid:

```
function testFunction(){ mySecondFunction(); }  //ran first
$(document).ready(function(){ // ran third;
        window.mySecondFunction = function(){alert("this will work");}
    });
testFunction(); // ran second
```

The reason is that the code inside the ready function is run after everything else is loaded. So when testFunction is run (last line), mySecondFunction is not defined. It's basically the same mistake you'd make if you tried:

```
function test() { test2() };
function test2() {alert('wtf?')};
```

Any code not in the ready function gets executed before any code in the ready function. However, any code executed AFTER the the document has loaded (and the ready function has fired) has access to mySecondFunction because it is now defined in the window scope. Consider the following.

```
function testFunction(){ mySecondFunction(); }
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.mySecondFunction = function(){alert("this will work");}
    });
//testFunction(); erroneous do not uncomment!
$(document).click(function() {testFunction();}); //works fine
//$("body").click(function() {testFunction();}); //does nothing
```

If you click on the document, you're clicking after the ready function is executed, hence the uncommented line works fine. The line after it does nothing (if this is in the `<head>` tag) because at this point there is no body, so `$("body")` returns an empty jquery list. The chronology of javascript is almost as confusing as the scope.

Comment: how do I call a function inside the $(document).ready(function() {}); function, from the outside.? example function testFunction(){ mySecondFunction(); }
$(document).ready(function(){

    function mySecondFunction(){alert("this won't work"); }

});

testFunction();

Comment: It's not possible. I'll explain why in my answer. It requires space.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function testFunction(){ alert("inside testfunction"); }
$(document).ready(function(){

    testFunction();

});
```

Comment: perfect, can you give me an idea of why this is occurring? is it some scope issue?

Comment: You shouldn't have to call the function in there.  That will just fly an alert.  Just remove the testFunction() inside the ready handler.

Comment: @Andre it's definitely a scoping issue.

Comment: As in answer, the testFunction should have global scope (outside the ready event handler) in order to be called from the #someid event handler

Comment: @Groovetrain yeah, that's what I did, it's working great now. Got it, this helped.

Comment: @Andre check out my answer. I spent a lot of time on it. :(